# Why SHA-256 used in Bittorrent v2?

Tags: bittorrent

Since collisions found in SHA-1, BitTorrent moved to more secure hash function SHA-2, but why not to create hash format representation like magnet:?xt=urn:bt_[hash_function_name]:info_hash ?

Example:
magnet:?xt=urn:bt_sha3:123456789101112131415

It's like 2+2 that people will continue building up more advanced computers.
And collisions can be made in near future, and looking into new protocol, we can already see that its adoption is happening very slowly, it wouldn't be nicest thing if say in 2030 new collision occured, then developers will have to change this protocol again?

V1 DHT is not compatible with V2 anyway.

So my noob question goes to @the8472

Comment: Probably it's to decrease the difficulty of writing protocol implementations, and to ensure everyone's clients and torrents are compatible. And they probably don't think collisions are very near on the horizon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's like 2+2 that people will continue building up more advanced computers.

The primary cause for collision attacks is weaknesses in the hash function. Faster computers only provide very modest improvements as for every additional bit you to twice as much compute power. Even the still quite hypothetical general purpose quantum computers would only cut down collision resistance from N/2 to N/3.

Also, collision attacks are not a major threat to bittorrent. They could break certificate based systems built on top of bittorrent, e.g. where some 3rd entity vouches for the correctness of content described by a hash. But the primary use of hashes in bittorrent (integrity, i.e. getting bit-exact copies of whatever the initial seed published) is only vulnerable to [preimage attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack).

> and looking into new protocol, we can already see that its adoption is happening very slowly, it wouldn't be nicest thing if say in 2030 new collision occured, then developers will have to change this protocol again?

Bittorrent v2 specifies a `meta version` field [in the info dictionary](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0052.html#info-dictionary) and requires that clients check for compatibility first before attempting to use the torrent, this will make future upgrades smaller and easier to roll out.
But they are not specified in advance since we don't know which hashes or other security-related changes will be needed in the future. Specifying and negotiating more than one supported cryptographic primitive tends to be error-prone and increases implementation complexity.

The [v2 magnet link](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html#magnet-uri-format) already provides flexibility by adopting the multihash format.

> V1 DHT is not compatible with V2 anyway.

That is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will read this BEP entirely before asking any other questions next time :)

Comment: "only vulnerable to preimage attacks" - this is incorrect. Attacker could use a collision search to create a colliding pair of files, one legit and one with some malware. He'd seed the legit file for a while to gain trust, only to later switch to seeding the malware file.

All he needs is some padding in the legit file where he can roll 20 bytes of entropy.

See here for some background: https://gitlab.com/bitcoin-cash-node/announcements/-/blob/master/2022-06-09_bitcoin_cash_pay_to_script_hash_p2sh_past_present_and_future_EN.md#322-plausibility-of-a-collision-attack

Comment: You can't attack an existing torrent by someone else, though, that would require cracking preimage, which is a 2^160 problem. Collision only works if you're creating both torrents yourself, and it's a 2^80 problem to generate a colliding pair for a 160-bit hash. Still too expensive (order of magnitude few million USD per collision), but not impossible.